# Perform a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, inner-join, query-performance

I have this query in PHP MySQL PDO:

```
SELECT p.las_plano_id, p.mensalidade_diferenciada, v.las_tipos_planos_id, t.valor_mensalidade 
FROM isw_planos AS p 
INNER JOIN isw_planos_vinculos AS v 
ON p.las_plano_id = 
      (SELECT v.las_plano_id 
       FROM isw_planos_vinculos 
       WHERE v.data_encerramento IS NULL 
       ORDER BY v.data_adesao 
       DESC LIMIT 1) 
INNER JOIN isw_planos_tipos AS t 
ON v.las_tipos_planos_id = t.id
WHERE p.ativo = 1
```

But.. the result generate a long delay.. it's possible to perform this query to execute more fast?

Thnaks..

Comment: The issue is related to PHP/PDO specifically? What does it do from the `mysql` interface?

Comment: Why not use [UNION?](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-union.php)

Comment: @user3783243 I use MysQL with PDO... but it makes no difference, I just want to improve the query

Comment: Okay, that is important for the question though. You don't want PDO/PHP improvements. Please add schemas for the tables and what an `explain` shows for this query execution path.

Comment: @Roshan .. the UNION is more fast than INNER JOIN? how would my query look please?

Comment: I suspect that there's scope to massively improve this query. But first, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is with `v.`:

This looks wrong: `SELECT v.las_plano_id ...` since v is outside the subquery. Please check the aliases used.

If removing `v.` does not help, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the indexes, etc.